# Desktop Chrome Header , position:fixed;

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, positioning, desktop

I am creating a mock up site for coding class. I just want a simple header that sticks to the top of the browser, and tried using `position:fixed;` to do so. In Chrome this basically shifted the header to the left and pushed all of my divs up underneath it. I fixed it in the mobile version using `margin-top` on the divs underneath it, but doing that on the desktop version just isn't working the same. Instead it just pushes my header even further down the page. Suggestions?

Here's my css if it helps. This is my first time doing an actual website so it's probably a mess, don't judge(okay, you can judge but at least tell me how to fix it):

```
#header{
color:#103251;
width:940px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-top:25px;
font-family:arial;
background-color:#B89EC9;
background-image:url('../images/utensils');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
position:fixed;
background-attachment:fixed;
}

@media screen and (max-device-width:426px){
#header{
    width:100%;
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: To position a `fixed` element, you don't need `padding`. You can use `left, top, right, and bottom`..

Comment: you can use padding-top to the divs underneath the header instead of using margin-top or you can use margin-top to the divs underneath and put top:0 to the fixed header

Comment: Using `left, top, right, and bottom` and `padding-top`  worked like a charm. Thanks!